# The easiest way to replace data from json file by data from API in Nuxt application

Tags: javascript, api, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I need help.
In a Nuxt application, I want to replace products coming from "../../data/products"
with an api call to 127.0.0.1/products

In store/products.js i have:

```
import products from "../../data/products";

const state = {
  productslist: products,
  products: products,
```

I tried this without success:

```
const actions = {
async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    const response = await this.$axios.$get("http:127.0.0.1:1337/products");
    const products = response.data;
    commit("setProducts", products);


enter code here
const mutations = {
  setProducts(state, products) {
    state.products = products;
```

Comment: Would [async data](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/) work for you in this case?

Comment: `const response = await this.$axios.$get("http://127.0.0.1:1337/products");`

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I found the solution.

Comment: Mounted() was needed.